# internal mailbox in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, email, internal

I would like to implement an internal mailbox in Spring MVC application. I tried to find something out myself and I surfed RabbitMQ, JMS, AMQP etc. but I am not sure if it is what do I need.  I want to allow my users to send messages among themselves but I do not mean a chat, it should be an internal mailbox, persisted to database. I am sure if I should one of mentioned frameworks and do persistance or there is another way? Could you give me some advises or links to get started with my problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need JMS or anything like that?  I have typically used those when I needed real-time sort of messaging on my site.  For a simple mailbox, just write the data to the DB on send and have a method to check if a particular use has messages waiting.  If you want to get fancy, you can AJAX-enable said method and have it check on some sort of timed loop.